# Tell me how to filter the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Need to get an array of houses that match these parameters

```js
const houses = [
    {id: 1, name: 'house1', floors: 2, balconies: 1, terrace: 'Y', veranda: 'N'},
    {id: 2, name: 'house2', floors: 1, balconies: "N", terrace: 'N', veranda: 'Y'},
    {id: 3, name: 'house3', floors: 3, balconies: 1, terrace: 'Y', veranda: 'N'},
    {id: 4, name: 'house4', floors: 1, balconies: "N", terrace: 'N', veranda: 'Y'},
    {id: 5, name: 'house5', floors: 1, balconies: "N", terrace: 'Y', veranda: 'N'},
    {id: 6, name: 'house6', floors: 3, balconies: 2, terrace: 'N', veranda: 'N'},
    {id: 7, name: 'house7', floors: 1, balconies: "N", terrace: 'Y', veranda: 'Y'},
    {id: 8, name: 'house8', floors: 2, balconies: 1, terrace: 'N', veranda: 'Y'},
]

const parameters = {floors: 1, terrace: 'Y', veranda: 'Y'}

const filterArray = houses.filter(house => {
    // Code
    
})
```

I tried it like this `Object.entries(parameters).some(e => e == house[e])`

I'm already confused. I tried using `includes`. Also nothing

I apologize for my English

Answer (score 5):

One fairly easy way is use `Object.entries()` to turn your parameters object into an array so you can use `paramsArray.every()` in your `filter()`.

This doesn't require you to know any of the specific properties in the parameters object or even how many there are, the only criteria is that they all have a matching value in the filtered objects

```js
const houses = [
    {id: 1, name: 'house1', floors: 2, balconies: 1, terrace: 'Y', veranda: 'N'},
    {id: 2, name: 'house2', floors: 1, balconies: "N", terrace: 'N', veranda: 'Y'},
    {id: 3, name: 'house3', floors: 3, balconies: 1, terrace: 'Y', veranda: 'N'},
    {id: 4, name: 'house4', floors: 1, balconies: "N", terrace: 'N', veranda: 'Y'},
    {id: 5, name: 'house5', floors: 1, balconies: "N", terrace: 'Y', veranda: 'N'},
    {id: 6, name: 'house6', floors: 3, balconies: 2, terrace: 'N', veranda: 'N'},
    {id: 7, name: 'house7', floors: 1, balconies: "N", terrace: 'Y', veranda: 'Y'},
    {id: 8, name: 'house8', floors: 2, balconies: 1, terrace: 'N', veranda: 'Y'},
]

const parameters = {floors: 1, terrace: 'Y', veranda: 'Y'};

const paramsArray = Object.entries(parameters)

const filterArray = houses.filter(house => paramsArray.every(([k,v])=> house[k] === v));

console.log(filterArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for...in` loop inside a `filter()` and filter the array. Try this-

```js
const houses = [
    {id: 1, name: 'house1', floors: 2, balconies: 1, terrace: 'Y', veranda: 'N'},
    {id: 2, name: 'house2', floors: 1, balconies: "N", terrace: 'N', veranda: 'Y'},
    {id: 3, name: 'house3', floors: 3, balconies: 1, terrace: 'Y', veranda: 'N'},
    {id: 4, name: 'house4', floors: 1, balconies: "N", terrace: 'N', veranda: 'Y'},
    {id: 5, name: 'house5', floors: 1, balconies: "N", terrace: 'Y', veranda: 'N'},
    {id: 6, name: 'house6', floors: 3, balconies: 2, terrace: 'N', veranda: 'N'},
    {id: 7, name: 'house7', floors: 1, balconies: "N", terrace: 'Y', veranda: 'Y'},
    {id: 8, name: 'house8', floors: 2, balconies: 1, terrace: 'N', veranda: 'Y'},
]

const parameters = {floors: 1, terrace: 'Y', veranda: 'Y'};

const filtered = houses.filter(house => {
  let retrunValue = true;

  for (const key in parameters) {
    retrunValue &&= house[key] === parameters[key];
  }
  
  return retrunValue;
});

console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score -1):

But if some parameters require extra rules, for example, the specified number of floors may be exceeded, you may want to code the rules explicitly:

```js
const filterArray = houses.filter (house => {
  if (house.floors < parameters.floors) return false; // too few floors
  if (parameters.terrace === "Y" && house.terrace === "N") return false; // missing terrace
  if (parameters.veranda === "Y" && house.veranda === "N") return false; // missing veranda
  // Something analogous for parameters.balconies
  return true; // Everything is OK
})
```

Comment: This will not scale, if for example the balconies get added to the parameters you will need to update the filter method too, as well as if there are more properties added to a house to filter on

Answer (score -1):

```js
const houses = [
  {id: 1, name: 'house1', floors: 2, balconies: 1, terrace: 'Y', veranda: 'N'},
  {id: 2, name: 'house2', floors: 1, balconies: "N", terrace: 'N', veranda: 'Y'},
  {id: 3, name: 'house3', floors: 3, balconies: 1, terrace: 'Y', veranda: 'N'},
  {id: 4, name: 'house4', floors: 1, balconies: "N", terrace: 'N', veranda: 'Y'},
  {id: 5, name: 'house5', floors: 1, balconies: "N", terrace: 'Y', veranda: 'N'},
  {id: 6, name: 'house6', floors: 3, balconies: 2, terrace: 'N', veranda: 'N'},
  {id: 7, name: 'house7', floors: 1, balconies: "N", terrace: 'Y', veranda: 'Y'},
  {id: 8, name: 'house8', floors: 2, balconies: 1, terrace: 'N', veranda: 'Y'},
]

const parameters = {floors: 1, terrace: 'Y', veranda: 'Y'};

const filtered = houses.filter((house) => {
  return house.floors === parameters.floors && house.terrace === parameters.terrace && house.veranda === parameters.veranda;
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: This will not scale, if for example the balconies get added to the parameters you will need to update the filter method too, as well as if there are more properties added to a house to filter on